# Reading multiple CSV files to DataFrames and naming them after their original file name

Tags: python, pandas

I had several csv files with same structure and I want

1. Assign file to dataframe name with the same order :
   `1.csv -> data1, 2.csv ->data2`
2. And assign columns in the same manner :
   `delta1 = data1["C"] - data1["A"]`

I want put it into the for loop, looks like this:

```
for i in range (1, 22):
    data%i = pd.read_csv('CSV/' + str(i) + '.csv')
    delta%i = data%i["C"] - data%i["A"]

# And I want to compare the 2 series from dataframe.column to find a set intersection
set(data1[data1.delta1 > 0].column) & set(data2[data2.delta2 == 0].column) 
set(data2[data2.delta2 > 0].column) & set(data3[data3.delta3 == 0].column)
```

but certainly wrong syntax in the for loop, is there better way to code it so that after the loop, I can get:

`data1, data2, data3` ...

with corresponding:

`delta1, delta2, delta3` ...

Comment: Sorry are you just asking how to add a new column? If so just do this: `data['delta'] = data['C'] - data['A']`

Comment: I mean how can I assign the df name as data1  data2 data3 etc when reading 1.csv 2.csv withih the for loop , is that possible ?

Comment: the name is a bit irrelevant, you can just append the resultant df to a list or dict, the name is just a reference to an object, why does this matter. Conceptually what you are asking doesn't make sense to me you'll need to explain better and edit this into your question

Comment: Oh, my purpose is to do the following :
data1[data1.delta1 > 0].column & data2[data2.delta2 = 0].column
And I need to do the same set operation for different dataframe

Comment: I'm saying you don't need to do that if you just had an empty list outside your for loop you can just do `data= pd.read_csv('CSV/' + str(i) + '.csv')
    data['deltae'] = data["C"] - data["A"]
    df_list.append(data)`

Comment: @EdChum: I think the OP is trying to use dynamically-created variables where a dictionary is appropriate.

Comment: @DSM yes I tried to explain that this is unnecessary as `data` will be just a temp inside the for loop but could be appended to a list or dict and referenced later

Comment: So I try to understand what you suggest is to :
let data1[data1.delta1 > 0].column , data1[data1.delta1 == 0].column to be appended to a list or dict outside the loop and then find intersection later ?  such as set[0] & set[1] ?

Comment: it's a bit strange what you are doing to have a df with delta%i as a column name, why not just delta? Also you could just have a single df if you prefer with columns delta1, delta2 .... and do your calculations on the whole df without losing identity

Comment: Oh, I see. pull the data outside the loop and compared/operated later ,rather then compared/operated inside the loop. 

I originally want to assign the i ( 1, 2,3 etc ) to the name of dataframe : data1, data2 , delta1, delta2 so I could operated later.  It seems not smart to do that ...

Comment: Try what I suggest and if you get stuck post your code and errors, also edit your question with any updated info. It's better to edit the question rather than leave it in the comments

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything with native pandas functions as opposed to dicts.

First read your csvs into a list:

```
df_list = []
for i in range(1, 22):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv("{i}.csv".format(i)))
```

Now concat them:

```
df = pd.concat(df_list, keys=range(1,22))
```

Now your dataframe `df` is indexed with the key of the file you loaded.

Doing for example `df.loc[1]` will get you the data from the file `1.csv`

You can now set your deltas witha a single operation:

```
df["delta"] = df["C"] - df["A"]
```

And you can access these deltas with the `DataFrame.loc` operation too, like this:

```
df.loc[2,"delta"]
```

This method is more native to `pandas` and may scale better with larger datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of what you want using dictionaries (as also suggested by @EdChum in the comments for example):

```
data = {}
delta = {}

for i in range (1, 22):
    data[i]= pd.read_csv('CSV/' + str(i) + '.csv')
    delta[i] = data[i]["C"] - data[i]["A"]

# And I want to compare the 2 series from dataframe.column to find a set intersection
set(data[1][data[1].delta[1] > 0].column) & set(data[2][data[2].delta[2] == 0].column) 
set(data[2][data[2].delta[2] > 0].column) & set(data[3][data[3].delta[3] == 0].column)
```

I would really recommend using a dictionnary such as above. However if you really really really insist on allocating variables dynamically like you want to do in your questions, you can do the following highly dangerous and not recommended thing:

You can allocate variables dynamically using:

```
globals()[variable_name]=variable_value
```

Again you really shouldn't do that. There is no reason to do it either, but here you go, here is the modification of your code which does **exactly** what you wanted:

```
for i in range (1, 22):
    datai = "data"+str(i)
    deltai = "delta"+str(i)
    globals()[datai] = pd.read_csv('CSV/' + str(i) + '.csv')
    globals()[deltai] = globals()[datai]["C"] - globals()[datai]["A"]

# And I want to compare the 2 series from dataframe.column to find a set intersection
set(data1[data1.delta1 > 0].column) & set(data2[data2.delta2 == 0].column) 
set(data2[data2.delta2 > 0].column) & set(data3[data3.delta3 == 0].column)
```